# Axial Chirality in Carbodiimides

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

Do carbodiimides exhibit axial chirality or do the nitrogens invert rapidly enough, as in trisubstituted amines with different alkyl groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, carbodiimides exhibit axial chirality similar to allenes. While there are significant differences in the allene - carbodiimide systems (see below) there are also some similarities. For example, just like in amines and imines the barrier to racemization in generally carbodiimidesis low, typically in the 6-10 kcal/m range.

Anet did a study on 1,3-diisopropylcarbodimide ("Energy barrier of racemization in diisopropylcarbodiimide", Frank A. L. Anet, J. C. Jochims, C. H. Bradley
J. Am. Chem. Soc., 1970, 92 (8), pp 2557–2558, DOI: 10.1021/ja00711a064).

[image]

In the chiral compound each isopropyl group would contain two diastereotopic methyl groups split by the isopropyl proton so we would expect to see 2 doublets. On the other hand, if racemization is rapid all methyl groups become equivalent and we would then expect to see only one doublet. Experimentally it turns out that around -150 C the doublet broadens into 2 doublets giving rise to a barrier height for racemization around 6.7 kcal/m.

**Important Notes:**

1) Just like with amines and imines, placing very electronegative groups on the carbodiimide nitrogens (fluorine, for example) raises the barrier to racemization.  Incorporating the carbodiimide structure into a small ring (see [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo951789c?src=recsys&journalCode=joceah) for an example) can also raise the barrier to enatiomerization.  Both techniques have been used to permit isolation of chiral carbodiimides.

2) Carbodiimides are not linear, but rather the $\ce{N-C-N}$ angle is around 170°.  This is attributed to the terminal nitrogens being more electronegative than the central carbon and consequently affecting the hybridization of the central carbon (*e.g.* changing it from $\ce{sp^1}$ to $\ce{sp^{x}}$ where 1            < x < 2)

3) Racemization in carbodiimides can be achieved by two different mechanisms

- by traditional nitrogen inversion involving a planar nitrogen atom, and/or
- by traditional cis-trans isomerization about the $\ce{C=N}$ double bond

both mechanisms are thought to play a role in carbodiimide racemization.

Comment: Could you elaborate note 3? How does racemization occur by planarization of nitrogen, as it is already planar?

Comment: I just mean the traditional nitrogen inversion transition state where the lone pair exists in a p-orbital and the other 3 ligands attached to nitrogen all lie in the same plane as the nitrogen. In the case of an imine or carbodiimide, 2 of the ligands are the pi bond. Think of the pi bond using the bent-bond (2-membered ring) formalism. Now the planar transition state occurs when the 2 bent-bonds and the R group attached to nitrogen and the nitrogen all lie in the same plane.

Comment: But aren't they already in a plane? The nitrogen is sp2.

Comment: No, the pi-bonds to nitrogen are in a different plane (orthogonal plane) than the plane containing the $\ce{N-R}$ bond. Again view the pi-bond as a two-membered ring, that might make the 2 planes easier to visualize.

Comment: @Marko Geez, you can call it linearisation here...

Comment: @Mithoron, if it is just like linearisation, how is that mechanism different from traditional cis-trans isomerisation about the C=N double bond?

Comment: @Ron Could you please draw both isomerisation process?

Comment: See this old Ron's answer   http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/26319/9961

Comment: I've edited the picture.  The "circle" between the C and the N on the right represents the pi bond or 2-membered ring bent-bond description. Does that help clarify the 2 processes?

Comment: Now I see what you meant. It's much easier to understand with diagram. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped.